# Mouse hover action is not highlighting the element

Tags: selenium, automation, mousehover

Problem : Mouse hover action is not highlighting the element . We are using selenium's mousehover() method.

What we tried : We tried the three solutions given in http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/mouse-hover-action/ link but none of it worked to achieve the goal.

Please let us know your advise or suggestion for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

which browser you are using because if you are using firefox and selenium 3.5 there is an issue regarding mouse actions which they are looking into it. I suggest try running it in chrome and check

Comment: I am using chrome 60+ and Safari 10+. Do you have any solution?

Comment: can you provide the code and exception you are getting while executing

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript for mouse hover. Please give below code try and let me know if its works:

```
    string javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                    "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";

    JavascriptExecutor js = = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

    //Pass element on which mouse hover to be performed
    js.executeScript(javaScript,element)
```

Pass you webelement in above line on which you want to perform mouse hover.